# What are the specifics and basics of connecting Serilog to a MSSQL database?

Tags: c#, serilog

What are the specifics and basics of connecting Serilog to a MSSQL database?  Here is what I have so far.  Can you please tell where I am going wrong?

In the app.config I have:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LogConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=data.dev.db.com,14330;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=DNA_Logs;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

In the C# code I have:

```
public Guid transactionGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

public string transactionGUIDString = string.Empty;

public StringWriter TraceLog = new StringWriter();

public void HelloLog()
{
    this.transactionGUIDString = transactionGuid.ToString("B").ToUpper();

    var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .Enrich.WithProperty("TransactionId", this.transactionGuid)
        .WriteTo.MSSqlServer("LogConnectionString", "Serilog_Logs")
        .WriteTo.TextWriter(TraceLog)
        .CreateLogger();

    // Output logs
    logger.Information("Hello, Serilog!");
}
```

And the database table is configured like this:

[image]

So I have a few questions.  First of all, since the database table is technically named "dbo.Serilog_Logs" shouldn't the C# code use this table name instead of just "Serilog_Logs"?

I found some sample code for Serilog but it only writes to the console.  I want to modify this sample code to write to the MSSQL Server.  I wonder how the columns of the table are supposed to be configured.

Comment: You need the SQL Server Name and Instance of Server.  Then set the initial database or add 'Use Database' in the connection string.  See : https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dbo.Serilog_Logs` default schema name is `dbo` if you didn't specify it, You can create your own schema using below SQL statement and mention it in configuration method arguments using `schemaName: "LOG"`

```
CREATE SCHEMA LOG;
```

Also make sure that database is exist and you have access to it throw your connection string, it database not exist create new one with below SQL command

```
CREATE DATABASE Serilog_DB;
```

And to configure table columns you can use `columnOptions` and define columns using `ColumnOptions` as below example

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LogConnectionString"].ToString();
var tableName = "Serilog_Logs";
var customColumnOptions = new ColumnOptions();
customColumnOptions.Store.Remove(StandardColumn.Properties); // Remove Column
customColumnOptions.Store.Add(StandardColumn.LogEvent); // Add new column to default columns

var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .Enrich.WithProperty("TransactionId", transactionGuid)
    .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString: connectionString
        , tableName: tableName
        , schemaName: "LOG" // Schema should be create in database first
        , columnOptions: customColumnOptions
        , autoCreateSqlTable: true) // Will create the table if a table by that name doesn't exist
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateLogger();
```

Result should be as below image

[image: Serilog Table and Columns]

Comment: @xarzu make sure that database is exist and you have access to it throw your connection string

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of how to create the table structure as well as how to configure the Sink is all described in the README of the repository

https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/

---

> ## [Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/)
>
> A Serilog sink that writes events to Microsoft SQL Server. This sink will write the log event data to a table and can > optionally also store the properties inside an XML or JSON column so they can be queried. Important properties can also be > written to their own separate columns.
>
> **Package** - [Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer](http://nuget.org/packages/serilog.sinks.mssqlserver)
>   | **Minimum Platforms** - .NET Framework 4.5.2, .NET Core 2.0, .NET Standard 2.0
>
> Topics
>
> - [Sink Configuration Options](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/#sink-configuration-options)
> - [Audit Sink Configuration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/#audit-sink-configuration)
> - [Table Definition](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/#table-definition)
> - [ColumnOptions Object](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/#columnoptions-object)
> - [SqlColumn Objects](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/#sqlcolumn-objects)
> - [Standard Columns](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/#standard-columns)
> - [Custom Property Columns](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/#custom-property-columns)
> - [External Configuration Syntax](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/#external-configuration-syntax)
> - [Troubleshooting](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/#troubleshooting)
> - [Querying Property Data](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/#querying-property-data)
> - [Deprecated Features](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/#deprecated-features)